# What is the difference between SingleEmailMessage and MassEmailMessage?

Tags: batch, singleemailmessage, massemailmessage, batchapexerrorevent

While i'm sending Email for 30 records both are getting Limit exceed Exception
Through Batch apex i give batch size as 10 but still getting exception.This is my code

```apex
global class ContactSingleMassMailBatchHandler implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id,Name,Level__c,Email FROM Contact]);
    }
    
    global void execute (Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> conList)
    {
         List<Messaging.MassEmailMessage>   mails = new List<Messaging.MassEmailMessage>();
      EmailTemplate et = [SELECT id, name, DeveloperName FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name ='ContactLevel'];
         
        for(Contact cc : conList)
        {
             if( cc.Level__c =='Secondary')
             {
                 List<Id> conIds = new List<Id>();
                 conIds.add(cc.Id);
                 Messaging.MassEmailMessage MSE = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
                 MSE.setTargetObjectIds(conIds);
                 MSE.setTemplateId(et.Id);
                 mails.add(MSE);
                
             }
        
        }
        Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
    }
     global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        System.debug('Execution Done All');
    }
}
```